# Jar via Tomcat in IntelliJ

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, jar

I spended a few hours to resolve my problem with deploying jar file on tomcat but I lost all fights, and I must ask one question:

**Is it possible to run the jar file via tomcat in intelliJ?**

Best regards

Comment: You deploy *war* files to Tomcat, not *jar* files. Perhaps it would be a good idea for you to read up on how to write Servlet code, you know, because Tomcat is a Servlet Container.

Comment: instead of using intellij,try to go to tomcat folder and go to webapps and place your jar there and open tomcat

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible deploy a jar in Tomcat anywhere. You can only deploy war files.

Normally when you distribute a web application in a jar (like a spring boot app) you don't deploy it in a server, it's a standalone application you run from the command line.

Comment: So, how to deploy Jar in IntelliJ? Which container I must use to run it?